# How do I selectively redirect my website?

Tags: web-hosting, website, html

I have a domain alias that i want to forward to a specific directory on my main site. How do I get it so that only people visiting the alias "fakesite.com" to be redirected to "mainsite.com/fake" instead of everyone redirected to that?

This is on the windows platform at myhosting.com

Comment: Please add details as to which web server software you're using.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what web server software you're using. It's most likely either IIS or Apache.

Answer (score 3):

Apache?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fakesite.com
    Redirect / http://mainsite.com/fake
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the fakesite.com site (in IIS) to be a permanent redirection to another webpage mainsite.com/fake

[image]

Should probably tick the "A permanent redirection for this resource" box and "the exact URL entered above"..